# Join several validation errors in Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

Lets say we have many radio buttons on our page and all of them are mandatory, our validation in controller would look like so:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('radio1', 'radio1', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('radio2', 'radio2', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('radio3', 'radio3', 'required');
//etc...
```

We would then display our errors:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    echo validation_errors();
}
```

But this displays error for every single radio button that isn't selected, you can potentially get hundreds of statements.

Is there a way using form validation helper to only display one error message if any of the radio buttons is left unchecked? Simply saying "Please check all radio buttons".

Comment: Your radios should have the same name attribute and only one rule should be set for that same name attribute.

Comment: @AdrienXL the ones that are in a group (ie. one group for car types, one group for house types)  do have the same name, other groups have different names

Comment: @Vagician `required` validation rule does not return error message when the form contains radio buttons" check [this](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/138). use hidden field and link with you radio button.

Comment: If you don't mind hacking a solution, what you can do is make all the error messages the same. Make the return errors into an array and do a array_unique() on that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a custom callback

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('radio1', 'radio1', 'callback_radio_check');
```

And the corresponding function written in your controller

```
    public function radio_check($input)
    {
        if ($this->post('radio1') || $this->post('radio2') || $this->post('radio3'))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('radio_check', 'This in an error message');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```